# Qual a diferença entre conjunção e preposição?

Tags: diferenças, sintaxe, preposições, conjunções

As preposições e conjunções são palavras de ligação entre termos de uma frase.

> Exemplo:
>   O menino segurou o brinquedo **com** as mãos?
>   Ordem **e** progresso.

com: preposição
e: conjunção
?

Qual a diferença entre conjunção e preposição?

Comment: Gramática Priberam: [conjunção](http://www.flip.pt/FLiP-On-line/Gramatica/Morfologia-Partes-do-discurso/Conjuncao.aspx) e [preposição](http://www.flip.pt/FLiP-On-line/Gramatica/Morfologia-Partes-do-discurso/Preposicao.aspx). Na sua frase, o "o" em "o brinquedo" é um artigo e não uma proposição.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A conjunção é uma palavra invariável que liga duas orações ou termos semelhantes de uma mesma oração.

A preposição também é palavra invariável que relaciona dois termos, só que, nessa relação, um termo completa ou explica o sentido do outro. A preposição não liga orações.

E como o Américo disse, esse "o" em "o brinquedo" é um artigo.

> Exemplos:

**Preposição:** As *coisas* **do** *Marcos* foram *atingidas* **pela** *mesa* (`do` e `pela` são preposições).

**Conjunção:** Gosto de Português **e** de Inglês. (Nessa frase as expressões de `Português` e de `Inglês` são partes ou termos de uma mesma oração. Logo, a palavra "e" está ligando termos de uma mesma oração.