# «Para» é preposição ou conjunção em «eu disse para ele se calar»?

Tags: sintaxe, preposições, conjunções, orações-subordinadas

Estas frases são semanticamente equivalentes:

> (a) Eu disse *para ele se calar*
>   (b) Eu disse-lhe *para (ele) se calar*
>   (c) Eu disse-lhe *que se calasse*

Em (c) a frase em itálico é uma oração subordinada substantiva objetiva direta (OSSOD), introduzida pela conjunção *que*: *que se calasse* é o objeto direto de “disse” (comparar com “eu disse-lhe isso”). As frases em itálico em (a) e (b) também são OSSOD, só que infinitivas e introduzidas por ***para***. [(Mais sobre orações subordinadas substantivas.)](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/16/deve-se-evitar-usar-v%C3%ADrgula-entre-ora%C3%A7%C3%B5es-subordinadas-substantivas-e-a-ora%C3%A7%C3%A3o-p/1429#1429) Por analogia com o *que* de (c), eu seria tentado a classificar este *para* como conjunção. Porém os dicionários classificam *para* só como preposição. Mesmo o Dicionário da Academia de Ciências de Lisboa (2001), o único onde encontrei exemplos deste tipo de frases:

> **para¹** […] **B.** Funções gramaticais […] **II.** Antes de infinitivo. […] **2.** Introduz frases infinitivas, sendo equivalente a uma frase completiva. *Pediu para as pessoas não se atrasarem. (Pediu que as pessoas não se atrasassem.)*

Porém Celso Cunha e Lindley Cintra (*Nova Gramática do Português Contemporâneo*, Lisboa, 2014, p. 731-2) diz:

> A nova terminologia no ensino do português […] considera que algumas palavras tradicionalmente classificadas como preposições (como *para* em orações subordinadas substantivas completivas não finitas e em orações subordinadas adverbiais finais não finitas) são, na verdade, conjunções.

Note-se que Cunha e Cintra observam esta posição, mas parecem não a adotar. Nomeadamente, eles classificam como preposição o *para* em todo os exemplos de orações subordinadas que dão. Mas também é verdade que eles não dão qualquer exemplo do tipo das minhas frases acima.

Nós já temos [esta pergunta sobre a diferença entre preposições e conjunções](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/599/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-conjun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-e-preposi%C3%A7%C3%A3o). Segundo a resposta que lá está, este *para* deveria ser uma conjunção, porque liga orações. Mas se este *para* aparece nos dicionários como preposição, o assunto é controverso. **Quais são então os argumentos e critérios para classificar este *para* como preposição ou conjunção?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, a tese de que *para* é aí um complementador é avançada por alguns. Por exemplo, Ana Brito na gramática de Maria Mateus e outras (pág. 392 da 6ª ed.):

> De um modo geral, tanto [as preposições como as locuções prepositivas] são categorias lexicais, porque seleccionam complementos e estão-lhes associados valores semânticos. Algumas preposições são essencialmente marcas de casos, [...] e outras, pelo menos em alguns dos seus valores, sofrem um processo de reanálise, comportando-se como complementadores, como acontece com *para*, quando introduz orações infinitivas:
>
> (1) Eu disse *para* tu vires.

Esta classificação deve-se ao facto de *para* não introduzir complementos nominais (cf. (e)) e de a distribuição ser semelhante à de *que* (comparar (a) e (b)). *Para* desaparece quando se substitui a oração subordinada infinitiva por um sintagma nominal, o que sugere que funciona como um complementador no interior da oração subordinada (compara com o par *pensei em ir* / *pensei **n**isso*).

> - (a) Eu disse *para tu vires*.
> - (b) Eu disse *que ele viesse*.
> - (c) */?Eu disse *para que ele viesse*.
> - (d) Eu disse *isso*.
> - (e) *Eu disse *para isso*.

O mesmo acontece com outros verbos diretivos, como *pedir*, *insistir*, *rogar* e *implorar* (ver Pilar Barbosa e Eduardo Raposo na *Gramática do Português* da Gulbenkian, pág. 1914-1915 e 1930).

Comment: Imagina que «essa» na primeira linha se refere à analogia que eu faço entre o *para* do meu exemplo (a) e o *que* de (b) e (c)? E a razão para ser preposição? É simplesmente por na maior parte dos usos ser preposição. E talvez originalmente ter sigo apenas usada como preposição?

Comment: @Jacinto OK clarifiquei qual era tese. Complementadores e preposições são geralmente tidas como classes distintas. Brito fala numa reanálise/recategorização de _para_, mas há propostas mais radicais, vê por exemplo http://www.clul.ul.pt/files/catarina_magro/trabalho_ID.pdf e os trabalhos que lá são citados em "d) Os trabalhos que exploram as afinidades entre P e C".

Answer (score 1):

O Ciberdúvidas, site português de gramática, classifica o "para" como conjunção final.
https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/conjuncoes-e-preposicoes/34609

Comment: Fernando, obrigado pelo link. O *para* do meu exemplo não é conjunção final. O artigo que tu linkas chama-lhe conjunção completiva ou integrante; tem até um exemplo quase igual ao meu: "pedi para te calares" (quase no fim do artigo).

Comment: Fernando, pode explicar melhor a sua resposta? Esse link pode ser uma boa sugestão, mas sua resposta não terá validade se um dia o link deixar de funcionar. Além disso, é importante para a comunidade ter conteúdo aqui no site mesmo. Seria melhor incluir mais detalhes na sua resposta. Um resumo do conteúdo do link já ajudaria bastante!